# Why does geom_text() throw coercion errors when hjust and vjust are strings?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've noticed an unexpected behavior in `ggplot2`'s `geom_text()` geom. If the attributes `hjust` and `vjust` are specified as strings, R returns coercion errors, though the plots seem to come out OK. The problem came up in a [ggplot2-based package](https://github.com/briandk/granova/tree/dev) I'm developing. For simplicity, I've created stripped-down examples that still produce the error.

First, I tried it with `qplot()`

```
##qplot version
library(ggplot2)
p <- qplot(cty, hwy, 
           label = drv, 
           hjust = "right", 
           geom  = "text", 
           data  = mpg
)

print(p)
```

And I got this error:

```
Warning message:
In validDetails.text(x) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

Then I tried it with `ggplot()`:

```
##ggplot version
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(
          aes(x   = cty,
              y   = hwy
          ), data = mpg
)

p <- p + geom_text(
           aes(label = drv),
           hjust     = "right"
)

print(p)
```

and got an identical plot, and an identical error:

```
Warning message:
In validDetails.text(x) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

I then tried setting both hjust and vjust:

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(
          aes(x   = cty,
              y   = hwy
          ), data = mpg
)

p <- p + geom_text(
           aes(label = drv),
           hjust     = "right",
           vjust     = "top"
)

print(p)
```

With both parameters set using strings, R returns two coercion errors:

```
Warning messages:
1: In validDetails.text(x) : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In validDetails.text(x) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

But, when the parameters are numbers, R returns no coercion errors:

```
## Using numbers instead of strings
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(
          aes(x   = cty,
              y   = hwy
          ), data = mpg
)

p <- p + geom_text(
           aes(label = drv),
           hjust     = 0,
           vjust     = 0,
           data      = mpg
)

print(p)
```

I'm not quite sure why this happens, or whether it's significant, but I didn't expect it.

#### ggplot2 documentations don't agree

[Hadley's book](http://books.google.com/books?id=F_hwtlzPXBcC&printsec=frontcover&dq=ggplot2&hl=en&src=bmrr&ei=DgJjTd3EBMGclgfs6ezhCw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CCcQ6AEwAA)(p. 196) says `hjust` and `vjust`
can accept string arguments:

> Justification of a string (or legend) defines the location within the
>   string that is placed at the given position. There are two values
>   for horizontal and vertical justification. The values can be:
>
> - A string: "left", "right", "centre", "center", "bottom", and "top".
> - A number between 0 and 1, giving the position within the string (from bottom-left corner).

But the man file for `geom_text()` in version 0.8.9 says hjust and vjust are numeric, though it *doesn't* say they can
*only* be numeric:

> Aesthetics
>
> The following aesthetics can be used with geom_text. Aesthetics are mapped to variables in the data with the aes function: geom_text(aes(x = var))
>
> - x: x position (required)
> - y: y position (required)
> - label: text label (required)
> - colour: border colour
> - size: size
> - angle: angle
> - hjust: horizontal justification, between 0 and 1
> - vjust: vertical justification, between 0 and 1
> - alpha: transparency

Comment: To be very particular, ggplot2 the book on page 196 does NOT say that hust and vjust can have those values... it only says (roughly) that "justification" can be one of... See my full "answer" below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, I don't know much about WHAT CODE defines or consumes hjust/vjust, but using TextMate's "Find in project" (in the ggplot2/R/ directory) for hjust, I don't see any lines that look like they are the definition of or the implementation of hjust... just places where it's listed as a valid aes and where it gets passed along.

That makes me want to go read grid...

http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/grid/html/grid.text.html

which leads me to want to know more about how grid.text is defined

```
R> grid.text

function (label, x = unit(0.5, "npc"), y = unit(0.5, "npc"), 
    just = "centre", hjust = NULL, vjust = NULL, rot = 0, check.overlap = FALSE, 
    default.units = "npc", name = NULL, gp = gpar(), draw = TRUE, 
    vp = NULL) 
{
    tg <- textGrob(label = label, x = x, y = y, just = just, 
        hjust = hjust, vjust = vjust, rot = rot, check.overlap = check.overlap, 
        default.units = default.units, name = name, gp = gp, 
        vp = vp)
    if (draw) 
        grid.draw(tg)
    invisible(tg)
}
<environment: namespace:grid>
```

so, it's a textGrob, and just, hjust, and vjust are simply being passed into it... off to textGrob

```
R> textGrob
function (label, x = unit(0.5, "npc"), y = unit(0.5, "npc"), 
    just = "centre", hjust = NULL, vjust = NULL, rot = 0, check.overlap = FALSE, 
    default.units = "npc", name = NULL, gp = gpar(), vp = NULL) 
{
    if (!is.unit(x)) 
        x <- unit(x, default.units)
    if (!is.unit(y)) 
        y <- unit(y, default.units)
    grob(label = label, x = x, y = y, just = just, hjust = hjust, 
        vjust = vjust, rot = rot, check.overlap = check.overlap, 
        name = name, gp = gp, vp = vp, cl = "text")
}
<environment: namespace:grid>
```

so, it's a grob........... off to grob......

```
R> grob
function (..., name = NULL, gp = NULL, vp = NULL, cl = NULL) 
{
    g <- list(..., name = name, gp = gp, vp = vp)
    if (!is.null(cl) && !is.character(cl)) 
        stop("Invalid 'grob' class")
    class(g) <- c(cl, "grob", "gDesc")
    validGrob(g)
}
<environment: namespace:grid>
```

Nothing too helpful there, so I Google

R grid hjust vjust

and after overriding Google's autocorrect of my search, I find

http://rwiki.sciviews.org/doku.php?id=tips:graphics-grid:hvjust

Looking back at Hadley's book, I notice that the p.196 reference doesn't actually MENTION hjust or vjust... simply justification.

Reading the documentation for

```
R> ?textGrob
```

I see that

```
just     The justification of the text relative to its (x, y) location. If there are two values, the first value specifies horizontal justification and the second value specifies vertical justification. Possible string values are: "left", "right", "centre", "center", "bottom", and "top". For numeric values, 0 means left alignment and 1 means right alignment.
hjust    A numeric vector specifying horizontal justification. If specified, overrides the just setting.
vjust    A numeric vector specifying vertical justification. If specified, overrides the just setting.
```

So, here's my thinking.

- the just parameter can be string or numeric
- hjust and vjust are numeric only and can override just
- if you try to use strings for them, it may "work", but throw warnings

So, lets look at the grid.text demo code and in particular the draw.text function where they use just and seem to do so successfully with string values:

```
grid.newpage()
x <- stats::runif(20)
y <- stats::runif(20)
rot <- stats::runif(20, 0, 360)
grid.text("SOMETHING NICE AND BIG", x=x, y=y, rot=rot,
          gp=gpar(fontsize=20, col="grey"))
grid.text("SOMETHING NICE AND BIG", x=x, y=y, rot=rot,
          gp=gpar(fontsize=20), check=TRUE)
grid.newpage()

draw.text <- function(just, i, j) {
  grid.text("ABCD", x=x[j], y=y[i], just=just)
  grid.text(deparse(substitute(just)), x=x[j], y=y[i] + unit(2, "lines"),
            gp=gpar(col="grey", fontsize=8))
}

x <- unit(1:4/5, "npc")
y <- unit(1:4/5, "npc")
grid.grill(h=y, v=x, gp=gpar(col="grey"))
draw.text(c("bottom"), 1, 1)
draw.text(c("left", "bottom"), 2, 1)
draw.text(c("right", "bottom"), 3, 1)
draw.text(c("centre", "bottom"), 4, 1)
draw.text(c("centre"), 1, 2)
draw.text(c("left", "centre"), 2, 2)
draw.text(c("right", "centre"), 3, 2)
draw.text(c("centre", "centre"), 4, 2)
draw.text(c("top"), 1, 3)
draw.text(c("left", "top"), 2, 3)
draw.text(c("right", "top"), 3, 3)
draw.text(c("centre", "top"), 4, 3)
draw.text(c(), 1, 4)
draw.text(c("left"), 2, 4)
draw.text(c("right"), 3, 4)
draw.text(c("centre"), 4, 4)
```

Now notice the difference if I change draw.text to use hjust and vjust **AS STRINGS**

```
grid.newpage()
x <- stats::runif(20)
y <- stats::runif(20)
rot <- stats::runif(20, 0, 360)
grid.text("SOMETHING NICE AND BIG", x=x, y=y, rot=rot,
          gp=gpar(fontsize=20, col="grey"))
grid.text("SOMETHING NICE AND BIG", x=x, y=y, rot=rot,
          gp=gpar(fontsize=20), check=TRUE)
grid.newpage()

draw.text <- function(just, i, j) {
  grid.text("ABCD", x=x[j], y=y[i], hjust=just[1], vjust=just[2])
  grid.text(deparse(substitute(just)), x=x[j], y=y[i] + unit(2, "lines"),
            gp=gpar(col="grey", fontsize=8))
}  

x <- unit(1:4/5, "npc")
y <- unit(1:4/5, "npc")
grid.grill(h=y, v=x, gp=gpar(col="grey"))
draw.text(c("bottom"), 1, 1)
draw.text(c("left", "bottom"), 2, 1)
draw.text(c("right", "bottom"), 3, 1)
draw.text(c("centre", "bottom"), 4, 1)
draw.text(c("centre"), 1, 2)
draw.text(c("left", "centre"), 2, 2)
draw.text(c("right", "centre"), 3, 2)
draw.text(c("centre", "centre"), 4, 2)
draw.text(c("top"), 1, 3)
draw.text(c("left", "top"), 2, 3)
draw.text(c("right", "top"), 3, 3)
draw.text(c("centre", "top"), 4, 3)
draw.text(c(), 1, 4)
draw.text(c("left"), 2, 4)
draw.text(c("right"), 3, 4)
draw.text(c("centre"), 4, 4)
```

Long story-short: I think when you use hjust or vjust as a string, you're violating the documentation (it's value should be numeric 0 <= x <= 1), and that if you want to use strings, you have to use the just parameter....

Comment: In looking through the documentation for `textGrob`, I guess my real question is: Why can't ggplot2's `theme_text()` just accept and pass along the `just` parameter so users can specify justification vectors like `just=c("bottom", "centre")`?

Comment: It _could_... it just _doesn't_. Perhaps this suggests a pull request for ggplot2?

Answer (score 1):

`hjust` and `vjust` should be numbers, check the manual (`?geom_text`):

- hjust’: horizontal justification, between 0 and 1
- ‘vjust’: vertical justification, between 0 and 1

Comment: I agree the manual says that hjust and vjust should be numbers. I've edited the question to reflect the fact that Hadley's book seems to pretty clearly specify that they can be strings as well. It's not clear to me which documentation supercedes which.

Comment: Code supersedes all documentation; documentation lies. :)